# useState is not updating state immediately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, use-effect, use-state

here **userlist** is updating immediately what can be correct code for above logic
I am trying fetch userlist from firestore than traversing that list to find user details from different collection

```
useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("following/" + Credens.uid + "/userFollowing")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        followingList = snapshot.docs.map((value, ind) => value.data());
      })
      .then(() => {
        if (followingList.length > 0) {
          followingList.map((value, index) => {
            db.collection("Postss")
              .doc(value.useruid)
              .collection("MovieWatched")
              .get()
              .then((snaps) => {
                // let Detail = snap.data()
                let movieidList = snaps.docs.map(
                  (value) => value.data().postMovieId
                );

                if (movieidList.includes(MovieId) === true) {
                  setuserList((prev) => [...prev, value.useruid]);
                }
              });
          });
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log(userList);
        userList.map((value, index) => {
          db.collection("users")
            .doc(value)
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
              setfriendsWatchedData((prev) => [
                ...prev,
                {
                  usersID: value,
                  userData: snapshot.data(),
                },
              ]);
            });
        });
      });

    // return () => {
    //     cleanup
    // }
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

To be sure the state did change, you can use the *useEffect()* to monitor the changing of that state like:

```
useEffect(() => { 
  if (userList) {
  // userList.map....
  } 
}, [userList])
```

Additional conditions can be specified in the if statement. The hook will run whenever the state changes.

Comment: it is causing useeffect to run infinitly, because userlist once update it will run useeffect again and again and userlist kept on increasing through duplicate items

Comment: Well yes, you should never change the value that use effect i listening to. I was under the impression that you just wanted to listen when it changes without making changes to the state itself (missed the mapping part). 

But you can stop the infinite loop by setting an additional bool argument after the map, and chage [userList] to [userList && boolValue].